# trying to create a filter to show data

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

im new here and i hope you can help me... so im building an inventory app.
there is a mongo db table contains products and every product have quantity and MinQuantity it must have.

im trying to create a filter when there is less available quantity than the minQuantity of the product it will show only there products in the table.
iv'e added two alerts just to test why the loop is stack on the first product in the table and not moving on to the following products..I hope i gave enough information, thanks

```
if (category == "Missing") {
document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").forEach((element) => {
  alert(Number(document.getElementById("prodMinQuantity").innerText));
  alert(Number(document.getElementById("prodQuantity").innerText));
  if (
    Number(document.getElementById("prodMinQuantity").innerText) >
    Number(document.getElementById("prodQuantity").innerText)
  ) {
    alert("fgfgfg");
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

}

Comment: so you have a `forEach` loop, but inside you are comparing elements with id `prodMinQuantity` and `prodQuantity`. If you have multiple elements with such ids, you can access only the first one with `getElementById()`

Comment: but i want to compare each product with its own quantity and minQuantity..and i have lots of products in the table

Comment: id attribute should should be unique. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table where each row contains columns with ids `prodMinQuantity` and `prodQuantity`, you should change that, because in HTML [`id` attribute must be unique in the document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:the-id-attribute-2).

It's better to use [`element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to store additional information instead.

If you insist on using `id` attribute, then you can use `document.querySelector()` instead:

```
if (category == "Missing") {
document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").forEach((element) => {
  const prodMinQuantity = ~~element.querySelector("#prodMinQuantity").innerText,
        prodQuantity = ~~element.querySelector("#prodQuantity").innerText;

  alert(prodMinQuantity);
  alert(prodQuantity);
  if (prodMinQuantity > prodQuantity {
    alert("fgfgfg");
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, now when im clicking on the popup to open the filter and select 
"Missing" its not opening, do you know what could cause it?

Comment: sorry, nobody could possibly answer this question without seeing the code. Check devtools console for error messages.